# Why I get all matches in one Matcher.find() execution in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

My input string is

"PING www.abc.com (172.217.160.132) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from maa03s29-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.132): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=50.9 ms

64 bytes from maa03s29-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.132): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=67.0 ms

64 bytes from maa03s29-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.132): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=81.6 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.995/66.591/81.693/12.537 ms"

and my pattern is

`(\\d+ bytes from [\\w\\W]+ \\(\\d+(\\.\\d+){3,3}\\): icmp_seq=\\d+ ttl=\\d+ time=[\\d+.]+ ms)`

I execute

```
       int count++;
      while(matcher.find()) {
        count++;
System.out.print(count+" ");}
```

My expected output 
`1 2 3`
 But My actual output
`1`
When i try to print matcher.group in while loop I got

64 bytes from maa03s29-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.132): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=50.9 ms

64 bytes from maa03s29-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.132): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=67.0 ms

64 bytes from maa03s29-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.160.132): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=81.6 ms

Why it find all matches in firstTime execution ?

Comment: Replace `[\\w\\W]+` with `.+`

Comment: Yes. it worked. Can you please how it worked and what mistake i made ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[\\w\\W]+` with `.+`:

```
(\\d+ bytes from .+ \\(\\d+(\\.\\d+){3,3}\\): icmp_seq=\\d+ ttl=\\d+ time=[\\d+.]+ ms)
#                ^^
```

- `[\\w\\W]+` stands for any character (including linebreak), greedy (it matches the most that it can) from the first `from` until the last `(172.....)`
- `.+` matches any character **but newline**

Comment: Thank you very much